# Wrong intents are getting trigger on the inappropriate User input in Dialog Flow

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I have few intents which are getting trigger on the inappropriate User input. Below are a few examples.

Intent 1). Training phrases I have given

> 1. When will I get a job abroad?
> 2. Is there any possibility that I will be settled in foreign
> 3. When will I settle in foreign

This intent is getting called for user input ***I had a fight with my friend, will it settle down***

Intent 2). Training phrases I have given

> 1. When my financial problems will over
> 2. Tell me about my financial condition
> 3. How will be my financial condition in the future
> 4. What will be my financial condition

This intent is getting called for user input ***When my family problems will over***

Please help me out to handle these scenarios.

Comment: The sentences are getting matched because they are similar to the examples. Its recommended to add at least 10+ examples to get started with intent recognition. This prevents issues like this.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/intents-training-phrases), you should use at least 10-20 trainning phrases.

> You don't have to define every possible example, because Dialogflow's
> built-in machine learning expands on your list with other, similar
> phrases. You should create at least 10-20 (depending on complexity of
> intent) training phrases, so your agent can recognize a variety of
> end-user expressions. For example, if you want your intent to
> recognize an end-user's expression about their favorite color, you
> could define the following training phrases:
>
> - "I like red"
> - "My favorite color is yellow"
> - "black"
> - "Blue is my favorite"
> - ...

Given that, to increase the assertiveness of your intents I'd recommend you creating more training phrases and focus them in the main terms necessary in your problem.